# Getting weird form of table

Tags: latex, tabular, miktex, texworks

Hi all if anyone can help me. I am new to latex. I am trying to add table in my latex. I know the format but i don't know what I am doing wrong because my table is not in the form I want moreover it is giving me the error when I add caption.

I need some thing like this in the image

[image]

but I am getting this when I compile my latex code

[image]

Here is my code:

```
\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}[!ht]{||c c ||} 
        \caption{Dataset Specifications}
        \centering \label{data}
 \hline
 Dataset & Samples \\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline\hline
 Vovid & 349 \\ 
 \hline
 noncovid & 397  \\ [1ex] 
 \hline


\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Your table would look much more professional if you would avoid vertical lines. Have a look at the documentation of the `booktabs` package for some inspiration on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My minimal code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1em}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    Dataset & Samples \\
    \hline
    Covid & 349 \\ 
    Non Covid & 397 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Dataset Specifications}
  \label{tab:data}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

and its output:

[image: screenshot of output]

Please comment below here if any feature is missing or something is not clear to you :)

Comment: thank you so much. this is exactly the way i want to have it in my pdf form. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

How about that:

```
\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
 \begin{tabular}{|c |c|} 
      
 \hline
 Dataset & Samples \\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline
 Vovid & 349 \\ 

 noncovid & 397  \\ [1ex] 
 \hline
    
\end{tabular} 
\caption{Dataset Specifications}
  \label{tab:data}
\end{table}
```

So, the trick is 1) to pack the tabular in a table environment, 2) play with \hline and | to modify the lines around the table cells. More ways to polish tables in https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables

Comment: Don't use the `center` environment inside floats - it adds unnecessary vertical spacing.